# manually writing a Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

So far I have seen documentation of how to write a storyboard with Interface Builder. I prefer writing the code manually though. Can a storyboard be developed manually without interface builder in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this, however, if you right click on your storyboard file in the Project Navigator choose the option Open As > Source Code you can hack away to your heart's delight.

I would imagine you'd prefer editing a Storyboard using IB as you'll just be creating more work for yourself debugging various syntax issues that the editor would have abstracted away for you. Note, that the XML is compiled at build-time into the binary files called nibs, then loaded and instantiated at run-time to create the views. Getting your hands dirty with that will slow you down.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW1

BTW @Kenny's suggestion to write your views in code is a good one if you really don't want to use XIBs or Storyboards

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer writing code, I would suggest doing everything programmatically and not using storyboards at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a text editor to write text files? Then use the storyboard editor to write storyboards.

At the end of the day, if you wanted to reverse engineer a storyboard file you could do that, and then hard code your own, new one using what you've learned.

Here's a clue: XML.

Alternatively, ignore storyboards completely, and just programatically create all your views, segues and transitions. That is perfectly feasible.

Comment: You mean there is no documentation for writing storyboard XIB from scratch? Like a list of tagnames...

Comment: Nope. They are not intended to be user-edited directly. And this is with the new, cleaner, more-diffable format. Prior to Xcode 5 (or was it 5.1?), they were horrifyingly messy and redundant.