# Can Xcode Add Items To A Storyboard, In Editor, Through Code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Does anyone know of a way to add elements to a storyboard (button, view, tab bar, etc) without going through the object library, for example with a custom editor button that could run code of some sort to add them?

Another way to ask this might be, is there a way to create an xcode storyboard containing x number of views, buttons, etc, and drop it into another xcode project and have it show up?

The storyboard does not need to work..so no code, outlets, actions, segues, etc...I'm just looking for a way to create a storyboard, with x views, buttons, etc.  I would then go in and make all the connections, code, etc.

Yes, I know how to create and work with storyboards, but I thought I would ask if it was possible.

Thanks.

Comment: very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25313883/793607

Comment: Thanks! Right after posting, it hit me to right click and look at the code... XML for the win.